# FMDB using online database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

I use FMDB to speak with the database from my app, and now I would like to put this database online so it will be possible to access it anywhere.

I found lot of ways, but nothing really interesting, and always very confusing.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't really open the database directly from a URL (if even possible). You should download it and cache it on the device first. You can either download the entire sqlite file or ditch FMDB and make a JSON interface, depends on the nature of your app and data.